# Are there polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, other than $P(x)=x^2$, such that $P(\sin x)+P(\cos x)=1$ for all real $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> Are there any polynomials $P\in\mathbb R[x]$, other than $P(x)=x^2$, such that
>     $$ P(\sin x) + P(\cos x) = 1,\quad x\in\mathbb R? $$

Notice that there are *pairs* of polynomials $P,Q$ with $P(\sin x)+Q(\cos x)=1$: say, from $\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$ and $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$ it follows that 
  $$ (3\sin x-4\sin^3 x)^2+(4\cos^3 x-3\cos x)^2=1. $$

My motivation for this question is a pure curiosity; hope it counts.

Comment: Certainly, $P(x) = \frac12$ will do

Comment: There's a whole family of those solutions @MatthewTowers: $ax^2 + \frac{1-a}{2}$ will work.

Comment: Apparently solved here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h129406p733854 : The general solution is $(x^2-1/2) R((x^2-1/2)^2) + 1/2$ for an arbitrary polynomial $R$.

Comment: @MartinR: amazing. How did you figure it out? Is there any search engine to check if a problem appears somewhere in the AoPS?

Comment: @W-t-P: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(%5Csin%20x)%20%2B%20P(%5Ccos%20x)%20%3D%201%24&p=1)

Comment: @W-t-P: Approach0 (and another search engine SearchOnMath) are mentioned here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10169/42969, see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969.  Only recently, Approach0 covers both MSE and Art of Problem Solving.

Answer (score 5):

This has been solved on Art of Problem Solving: [Polynomial - TUYMAADA-2000](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h129406).

Assume that $P$ is a polynomial satisfying
$$ \tag{*}
\forall x \in \Bbb R: P(\sin x) + P(\cos x) = 1 \, .
$$

- First show that $P(-y) = P(y)$ for all $y= \sin(x) \in [-1, 1]$ and conclude that $P$ is even, i.e. $P(x) = Q(x^2)$ for some polynomial $Q$.
- Then show that $Q(\frac 12 +y) + Q(\frac 12 - y) = 1$ for all $y = \sin^2(x) - \frac 12 \in [-1/2, 1/2]$, and conclude that $Q(\frac 12 +y) - \frac 12$ is odd, i.e. $Q(\frac 12 +y) - \frac 12 = y R(y^2)$ for some polynomial $R$.

It follows that
$$
 P(x) = (x^2- \frac 12) R((x^2 - \frac 12)^2) + \frac 12
$$
for a polynomial $R$. Conversely, every such polynomial satisfies $(*)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer for $P(\sin^2x)+P(\cos^2x)=1.$

With $t:=\sin^2x-\frac12$, we have the functional equation
$$P\left(\frac12+t\right)+P\left(\frac12-t\right)=1,$$

so that $Q(t):=P(t+\frac12)+\frac12$ is an odd function of $t$, such as a polynomial with odd terms.

With $Q(t)=t$, $P(t)=t-\frac12+\frac12=t$.

With $Q(t)=t^3$, $P(t)=(t-\frac12)^3+\frac12=t^3-\frac32t^2+\frac34t+\frac38.$

And so on.

Also, with $Q(t)=16t^3-3t$, $P(\sin^2x)=\sin^2x(3-4\sin^2x)^2$.